# Can i install ROS2 on the same machine which alrerady has ROS installed?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I worked with ROS for a couple of weeks and now need to upgrade to ROS2 due to its DDS feature. Although i know that ROS2 offers a bridge for ROS1 but just to be sure i want to ask if i can install ROS2 on the same machine as ROS or shall i create another VM to install ROS2 seperately ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286978/can-i-install-ros2-on-the-same-machine-which-alrerady-has-ros-installed-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> i can install ROS2 on the same machine as ROS

Yes.

If you're using Ubuntu Xenial as your OS you could even use the provided binaries ([Installing ROS2 via Debian Packages](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Install-Debians)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-03-29**:
And what if i want to do it the other way round ? i.e. I installed ROS2 first (from source) and then I want to use to features of ROS using the ROS bridge. Is it then possible ? As now i dont have any ROS installed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
Provided you are using an OS that is supported by ROS1 it should be possible.